# how to count nonzero elements in a matrix?

Tags: c#, .net, matrix

I have a matrix with two values (0,1), I have to count the number of "1" in this matrix, so I tried to check all elements but for [1000,1000] matrix, it takes too long, and another problem is, I should do this many times for different matrices, so I hope anyone could help me with a faster mode.

here is my code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < matrix.height; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < matrix.width; j++)
    {
        if (matrix[j, i] == 1)
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `matrix` an instance of your custom class? If so please [edit] your question and include that class definition

Comment: If the number of 1's is much lower than the number of 0's (or vice versa) you could use a [Sparse Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix).

Comment: Did this as a project in college.  Created a Sparse  Matrix using link objects.  See wiki : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually have multiple options if you implement matrix class yourself:

```
public class BoleanMatrix
{
     public bool this[int i, int j] {get;set;}
}
```

1. Cache it. Its easy. Upon any modification just update cached value of high bits. Implementation is irrelevant.

   ```
   public class BoleanMatrix
   {
       private int _highBitCount = 0;
       public bool this[int i, int j] 
       {
           get;
           set
           {
               if(prev != value)
               { 
                   if(value)
                       _highBitCount++;
                   else
                       _highBitCount--;
               }
               //set here
            }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Change implementation to any sparse variant, for example, you can store matrix values as bits in byte[] array. If it is still too much - compress it with Run Length Encoding. It comes with drawbacks such as update and distribution problems of those matrix and usually they much slower than memory wide matrix. Efficient algorithm highly depends on nature of your matrix (distribution of values) and how you use them (multiplication, division, substraction, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Given that you are only storing bits, you can improve the storage usage by storing the bits packed into `uint` values, which will reduce the amount of space required by a factor of 32 compared to using `int` for each value.

If you do that, then you can also more efficiently count the number of set bits by using one of many different ["Hamming Weight"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_weight) algorithms.

The drawback of this approach is that it may be slower to access the individual bits using the array `BitMatrix` indexer, but the computation of the number of set bits is much faster (more than 90 times faster for RELEASE mode builds on my PC).

Here's the sample code; the important class is `BitMatrix`:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Demo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            int[,] matrix = new int[1000, 1000];
            BitMatrix bitMatrix = new BitMatrix(1000, 1000);

            // Randomly populate matrices and calculate expected count.

            var rng = new Random(985912);
            int expected = 0;

            for (int r = 0; r < 1000; ++r)
            {
                for (int c = 0; c < 1000; ++c)
                {
                    if ((rng.Next() & 1) == 0)
                        continue;

                    ++expected;
                    matrix[r, c]    = 1;
                    bitMatrix[r, c] = true;
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Expected = " + expected);

            // Time the explicit matrix loop.

            var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
                if (count1(matrix) != expected)
                    Console.WriteLine("count1() failed");

            var elapsed1 = sw.ElapsedTicks;
            Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed);

            // Time the hamming weight approach.

            sw.Restart();

            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
                if (bitMatrix.NumSetBits() != expected)
                    Console.WriteLine("NumSetBits() failed");

            var elapsed2 = sw.ElapsedTicks;
            Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed);

            Console.WriteLine("BitMatrix matrix is " + elapsed1 / elapsed2 + " times faster");
        }

        static int count1(int[,] matrix)
        {
            int h = 1 + matrix.GetUpperBound(0);
            int w = 1 + matrix.GetUpperBound(1);

            int c = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < h; ++i)
                for (int j = 0; j < w; ++j)
                    if (matrix[i, j] == 1)
                        ++c;

            return c;
        }
    }

    public sealed class BitMatrix
    {
        public BitMatrix(int rows, int cols)
        {
            Rows = rows;
            Cols = cols;
            bits = new uint[(rows*cols+31)/32];
        }

        public int Rows { get; }
        public int Cols { get; }

        public int NumSetBits()
        {
            int count = 0;

            foreach (uint i in bits)
                count += hammingWeight(i);

            return count;
        }

        public bool this[int row, int col]
        {
            get
            {
                int n = row * Cols + col;
                int i = n / 32;
                int j = n % 32;

                uint m = 1u << j;

                return (bits[i] & m) != 0;
            }

            set
            {
                int n = row * Cols + col;
                int i = n / 32;
                int j = n % 32;

                uint m = 1u << j;

                if (value)
                    bits[i] |= m;
                else
                    bits[i] &= ~m;
            }
        }

        static int hammingWeight(uint i)
        {
            i = i - ((i >> 1) & 0x55555555);
            i = (i & 0x33333333) + ((i >> 2) & 0x33333333);
            return (int)((((i + (i >> 4)) & 0x0F0F0F0F) * 0x01010101) >> 24);
        }

        readonly uint[] bits;
    }
}
```

If you are running 64-bit code, then it's actually more efficient to use an array of `ulong` and calculate a 64-bit hamming weight.

When I tried that on my PC, it was more than 120 times faster.

Here's the 64-bit version of `BitMatrix`:

```
public sealed class BitMatrix
{
    public BitMatrix(int rows, int cols)
    {
        Rows = rows;
        Cols = cols;
        bits = new ulong[(rows*cols+63)/64];
    }

    public int Rows { get; }
    public int Cols { get; }

    public int NumSetBits()
    {
        int count = 0;

        foreach (ulong i in bits)
            count += hammingWeight(i);

        return count;
    }

    public bool this[int row, int col]
    {
        get
        {
            int n = row * Cols + col;
            int i = n / 64;
            int j = n % 64;

            ulong m = 1ul << j;

            return (bits[i] & m) != 0;
        }

        set
        {
            int n = row * Cols + col;
            int i = n / 64;
            int j = n % 64;

            ulong m = 1ul << j;

            if (value)
                bits[i] |= m;
            else
                bits[i] &= ~m;
        }
    }

    static int hammingWeight(ulong i)
    {
        i = i - ((i >> 1) & 0x5555555555555555UL);
        i = (i & 0x3333333333333333UL) + ((i >> 2) & 0x3333333333333333UL);
        return (int)(unchecked(((i + (i >> 4)) & 0xF0F0F0F0F0F0F0FUL) * 0x101010101010101UL) >> 56);
    }

    readonly ulong[] bits;
}
```

Observation: It turns out to be marginally faster to use `for()` rather than `foreach` in the loop in `NumSetBits()`, for example:

```
public int NumSetBits()
{
    int count = 0;

    for (var index = 0; index < bits.Length; index++)
        count += hammingWeight(bits[index]);

    return count;
}
```

On my PC this changes the performance from 120 times faster to 130 times faster.

Finally: If you want to take advantage of multithreading, you can do so like so (note the use of a `Partitioner` - this is to increase the block size of data calculated by each thread to make it a lot more efficient):

```
public int NumSetBits()
{
    int count = 0;
    var partitioner = Partitioner.Create(0, bits.Length);

    Parallel.ForEach(partitioner, (range, loopState) =>
    {
        int subtotal = 0;

        for (int i = range.Item1; i < range.Item2; ++i)
        {
            subtotal += hammingWeight(bits[i]);
        }

        Interlocked.Add(ref count, subtotal);
    });

    return count;
}
```

With this change, the Hamming approach is almost 200 times faster (and almost 300 times faster for a 2000x2000 matrix), but note that the amount by which it is faster depends on the proportion of 1 bits set.

Answer (score 0):

Try a parallel for loop ? If it can't be cached.

```
        object mylock = new object();
        int count = 0;

        Parallel.For(0, matrix.height, i =>
        {
            int forcount = 0;

            for (int j = 0; j < matrix.width; j++)
            {
                if (matrix[j, i] == 1)
                {
                    forcount++;
                }
            }

            lock (mylock)
            {
                count += forcount;
            }
        }
        );
```